# How does ReactNative monitor if a page is touched

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I now have a functional requirement, which needs to identify in ReactNative whether the page is used within three seconds (such as touch, click, swipe, etc.) If it is not in use, it needs to return to the standby page I specified. If it is not in use, it will not jump to keep the original page If I use Pressable in the outermost layer it will cause the slides, buttons, etc. on my page to be covered up and not perform how do I achieve the functionality I need now?

I hope that it can be used globally or encapsulated as hook without repeated work to implement this function. At present, I have no idea how to operate this function. Can you help me figure out how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new component with the TouchableWithoutFeedback component to detect taps / gestures and pass in the children prop to this component for reuse.

Since you want this to work only for the first 3 seconds, I would also set a timeout function to disable the functionality after 3 seconds.

```
import { TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native'

function TouchableWithoutFeedbackComponent({children}) {

  const [interacted, setInteracted] = useState(false);
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false); 

  const onPress = () => {
    setInteracted(true);
  };

  setTimeout(() => {
      setDisabled(true);
  }, 3000);

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback disabled={disabled} onPress={onPress}>
        {children}
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: This approach causes buttons and gestures on the page to be blocked. I've tried this